# How to test conditional ActiveRecord after_update callback with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have a conditional callback that triggers a job. If the manager changes, it should call the method

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :employee_manager_on_change, if: :employee_id_changed?

  def employee_manager_on_change
    EmployeeManagerChangedJob.perform_later(id)
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble to test this. I needed something like

```
context 'when changing manager' do
  subject { user.manager = new_manager }

  it 'calls employee_manager_on_change' do
    expect { suject.run_callbacks :update }.to receive(:employee_manager_on_change)
  end
end
```

Anyone knows what's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the gem [shoulda-callback-matchers](https://github.com/jdliss/shoulda-callback-matchers)

```
context 'callbacks' do
  it { is_expected.to callback(:employee_manager_on_change).after(:update).if :manager_id_changed? }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything like this?

```
context 'when changing manager' do
  before { user.manager = new_manager }

  it 'calls employee_manager_on_change' do
    user.save
    expect(user).to receive(:employee_manager_on_change)
  end
end
```

You can even specify how many time the method has to be called

```
expect(user).to receive(:employee_manager_on_change).once
```