# Rspec: testing callback is fired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an `after_update` callback on my model and I'm trying to test that it fires correctly however it seems like it's not being called at all:

```
class HealthProfile < ApplicationRecord
    after_update :send_office_email, if: -> { should_send_office_email }

    def should_send_office_email
        p "prev: #{previous_changes.keys.include?("step")}"
        p "status: #{status == 'start'}"
        p "step: #{step == '4'}"
        previous_changes.keys.include?("step") && status == 'start' && step == '4'
    end
end

RSpec.describe HealthProfile, type: :model do
    let!(:client) { create(:client) }
    let!(:intro_hp) { create(:health_profile, client_id: client.id)}

    # passes
    it "should not send office email unless complete" do
        expect(intro_hp).not_to receive(:send_office_email)
        intro_hp.update(signature: "t")
    end

    # fails
    it "should send office email if complete" do
        expect(intro_hp).to receive(:send_office_email)
        intro_hp.update(step: "4")
    end
end
```

Result:

```
Failures:

  1) HealthProfile should send office email if complete
     Failure/Error: expect(intro_hp).to receive(:send_office_email)

       (#<HealthProfile id: 2, name: "Brendan"...)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/models/health_profile_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The reason I think the callback is not being called in the test is because there is nothing printing to my terminal despite there being 3 print statements inside `should_send_office_email`.

What am I missing?

**EDIT: Showing factory:**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :health_profile do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    dob { (Date.today - 25.years).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }
    association :location
    weight { 100 }
    height { "5' 10" }
    desired_weight { 100 }
    informed { 'Friend / Family'}
    pacemaker { true }
    status { 'start' }
    marital_status { 'married' }
    children { true }
    children_ages { "5 and 7" }
    stress_source { "work!" }
    occupation { 'JOB!' }
    weightloss_success { true }
    weightloss_fail { true }
    weightloss_success_times { 2 }
    weightloss_unsuccess_times { 2 }
    other_programs { "WW"}
    exercise { true}
    exercise_type {"weights"}
    exercise_freq {'daily'}
    weightloss_desire {10}
    daily_stress{10}
end
```

Comment: What is `:no_callbacks`? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @jvillian: it's a custom FactoryBot trait, I assume. Can be anything. Including, indeed, suppressing callbacks somehow.

Comment: My apologies.  I've edited the question.  Removing that did not change my outcome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475287/how-to-test-conditional-activerecord-after-update-callback-with-rspec

Comment: "update - Updates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass." - is there a validation that prevents the saving?

Comment: It's saving successfully.  I'm very confused as to why I don't even see the terminal logging the lines from `:should_send_office_email`

Comment: I also tried the gem you showed above and that fails as well.